# systemd OpenVPN instance dependency

Tags: systemd

Got an OpenVPN instance X that requires a Dante proxy to be started on the same machine (as it will be using the proxy to connect to its target). I'd like to setup a dependency in `systemd` for `openvpn@X.service` (and only for this instance) to wait for `danted` to be started.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `danted` service is also started via `systemd` and is defined as `danted.service`, you may want to use the two `[Unit]` options `Requires` and `After`.

- `Requires=` will list other services that are required to start your actual service. In your case that would be `danted`. Additionally, when `openvpn@X.service` is started, `danted.service` is started as well automatically.
- `After=` ensures, that the `openvpn` service is started after `danted`. `Requires` only would start the two services simultaneously, which probably would fail your openvpn service.

To attach this to your `openvpn@X.service` only, best would be to use `systemctl edit openvpn@X.service`. This will open an editor (which one, refer to `man systemctl` and `SYSTEMD_EDITOR`) in which you can just add your changes.

```
[Unit]
Requires=danted.service
After=danted.service
```

This will create the file */etc/systemd/system/openvpn@X.service.d/override.conf* which will contain the changes/additions. Any changes/additions in this *override.conf* file will take precedence over the settings in `/lib/systemd/system`.
So you also could create the directory and path manually.

After saving your changes, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to activate the changes.

---

You also might want to have a look at the other available dependencies for a `systemd` unit, which are explained in `man systemd.unit`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a way to make sure the override is applied? I'd already done `systemctl edit ...` bit, but I'm not convinced it actually works. When I do `systemctl status openvpn@X` is can see a `override.conf` under `Drop-In` but when I do `show`, `Requires=` doesn't include `danted.service` (also starting `openvpn@X` won't start `danted`).

Comment: @marius-O: Did you use `danted.service` and did a `systemctl daemon-reload` after your last changes?

Comment: @marius-O: Don't worry... =0)